# Why are my files being transfered at only around 4 MB/second to my external Harddrive

Tags: external-hard-drive

Why are my files being transfered at only around 4 MB/second to my external Seagate Hardrive which is using USB 2.0. Is it also normal for you to hear clicking noises from the external hardrive?

Comment: If you hear clicking noises from a hard drive make a backup NOW, then go out and buy a new drive.

Answer (score 2):

You can see a poor transfer rate like this if you're running it through a USB hub or other cheap equipment.  Is it plugged into one of the motherboard slots at the back of your computer, and does the motherboard have usb drivers installed?

I would be pretty worried about the clicking noise though, normally I don't hear that outside of a five year old hard drive on its way out.

Answer (score 1):

What model is your Seagate harddrive? Are you sure it's plugged into a usb2 port (rather than usb1). Clicking isn't usually a good noise to hear from a hard drive. How old is it? Has it been dropped or knocked recently? Has it always made this noise?

Comment: It just came in the mail today so its brand new! This is the hard-drive Seagate Desk ST315005FDA2E1-RK External Hard Drive - 1.5TB, USB 2.0, Silver

Comment: user71122, you can check here to see if it requries a firmware update:http://seagate.custkb.com/seagate/crm/selfservice/search.jsp?DocId=207931

However I would advise that you return it, I would not expect a brand new drive to make these clickign noises

Comment: if it's brand new, return it immediately for replacement.  It should NOT be clicking

Answer (score 1):

This webpage: http://datacent.com/hard_drive_sounds.php will let you diagnose most of disk noises, so you can have an idea of what's going on inside your disk.

Anyway, clicking noises are never good; and you should back up the disk ASAP.
It can also have impact on R/W speeds.

Can the noise be related to you trying to read and write different sectors of the disk at the same time? (e.g.: watching a movie while copying another, both on the same disk)

Comment: Wow.. That site is officially AWESOME! Thank you for sharing!

Comment: I was reading and writing different sectors of the disk. That is probably why it was making clicking noises. Do you suggest I still return it although I was doing multiple things at once on this one disk?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read and write different sectors of the disk at once then it is *absolutely* normal to hear click sounds from the heads, as they are swiftly swapping possitions between one sector and another, and that should not be taken as a bad quality disk or anything. It's just something normal.

The only solution for that is to first copy what you want to another disk (i.e., a movie you want to watch) and then transfer whatever you wanted to the Seagate.